# Missing character in sed grouping

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to get an IP from a string by using sed grouping and I can't figure out what is wrong with this.

input:

```
echo "instream(10.20.213.11@40266):" | sed -E 's/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

output:

```
0.20.213.11
```

Why is the first number missing?

Comment: First `.*` is too greedy and matching `1` also. You may use: `sed -E 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `.*` that matches *greedily* to a `.*[^0-9]` requiring a non-digit char before the subsequent digit matching regex part:

```bash
sed -E 's/.*[^0-9]([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

It will work since IP addresses in your string are not at the start of the string.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/0FrMrk):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "instream(10.20.213.11@40266):" | \
  sed -E 's/.*[^0-9]([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/'
# => 10.20.213.11
```

If your IP addresses can be at the string start, you can use

```bash
sed -E 's/(.*[^0-9]|^)([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}).*/\2/'
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/jyTv4X). Here, `(.*[^0-9]|^)` matches either any text up to the right-most non-digit or start of string. Now, the IP address matching pattern will land in Group 2, hence is the use of `\2` in the replacement (RHS).

If your `sed` supports word boundaries, consider using word boundaries:

```bash
sed -E 's/.*\b([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3})\b.*/\1/'
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/hDwvAx), too.